# Selecting specified DOMElement value with laravel goutte / DOMCrawler - The current node list is empty error

Tags: php, laravel, goutte, domcrawler

I have a page that renders html like this:

```
<div class="details">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th class="field">Title</th>
            <td class="value">Laravel for Noobs</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th class="field">Type</th>
            <td class="value">PDF Book</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

What I want to do is iterate through each `<tr></tr>` and parse the value of the `<th class="field">???</th>` and `<td class="value">???</td>`.

For example, I want to generate an array like this from the above html:

```
$details = [
    ['field' => 'Title', 'value' => 'Laravel for Noobs'],
    ['field' => 'Type', 'value' => 'PDF Book']
];
```

Based on what I can see from the documentation(s):

- https://github.com/dweidner/laravel-goutte
- https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte
- https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html

I tried the following:

```
$details = [];
$crawler->filter('.details table tr')->each(function ($node) use(&$details) {
    $field = $node->filter('th .field')->first()->text();
    $value = $node->filter('td .value')->first()->text();
    $details[] = [
        'field' => $field,
        'value' => $value
    ];
});
```

When I try the above, I get the following error:

> The current node list is empty.

Any ideas on how to achieve this? Is it possible to further filter a node, after initial filter?

Comment: What happens when you change `$node->filter('th .field')` to `$node->evaluate('th.field')`? BTW, `th .field` looks for _descendants_ of `th` with class `field`; whitespace has meaning in CSS selectors.

Comment: @raina77ow This `echo $node->evaluate('th.field')->first()->text();` also gives me same error.